# Is UNIQUE-X3C a US-complete problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, complexity-classes

The problem: Exact Cover by 3-Sets (X3C)

The definition: Given a set X, with |X| = 3q (so, the size of X is a multiple of 3), and a collection C of 3-element subsets of X.  Can we find a subset C’ of C where every element of X occurs in exactly one member of C’?  (So, C’ is an “exact cover” of X).

The class US (Unique Polynomial-Time) is the class of decision problems solvable by an NP machine such that the answer is 'yes' if and only if exactly one computation path accepts.

UNIQUE-3SAT is the problem of deciding whether the 3CNF Boolean formulas have a unique solution. UNIQUE-3SAT is a known US-complete problem.

Is the version of problem Exact Cover by 3-Sets(UNIQUE-X3C) when the instances have a unique solution a US-complete problem? (which means there is a unique subset C’ as solution)

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This sounds very similar to [3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-dimensional_matching).

Comment: I think the right term of this class is [UP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UP_(complexity))?

Comment: @WillardZhan : ​ That's just a different class. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Oh, I see. Multiple certificates in this class indicate a 'no' instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

This [scanned chapter 3](http://pages.di.unipi.it/luccio/GJ%20Cap%203.PDF) from Garey-Johnson classic book describe a parsimonious reduction from **3SAT** to **3DM**. And **X3C** is a generalization of **3DM**. So, the same reduction can be used to **parsimoniously reduce** **3SAT** to **3DM**.

Thus, $\mathrm{UNIQUE-3SAT}$ many-one reduces to $\mathrm{UNIQUE-X3C}$. As a consequence, $\mathrm{UNIQUE-X3C}$ is $\mathrm{US}$-complete.